# Set cookie in default browser using c# desktop application

Tags: c#, wpf, browser, desktop-application

I am trying to open a url which needs username/psw combination from a desktop app. Desktop app already has an authentication mechanism. What i want is if someone tries to open the url then i'll pass the access token from desktop app to the web, so that user don't need to login again. 
One crude way to do this is to check the default browser using registry and depending on the default browser set the cookie in their local sqllite file(for chrome and firefox). But this approach doesn't seems to be the good one.
Is there any other way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

The most crude way would be to pass it as a query string parameter.  This may not be ideal as you might not want it to show, although you could have the target site do a quick redirect after authenticating.  You also want to be sure to only do this over HTTPS.

Another way if you'd prefer to POST the data would be to write out a local HTML file with a form that auto submits on load.  Have the access token in a hidden field on the form.  This would allow you to do a POST.

In either case, you can launch a browser to a specific page using `Process.Start("https://example.com/mypage")`.